# R Indicate If Group Has Value

Tags: r, data.table, pipe

```
data=data.frame(GROUP=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
VAR=c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'),
SCORE=c(3,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,5,5,2,NA),
NEWVAR=c(1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,1,1,1))

score1 = c(2,3,7)
score2 = c(0,5,6)
```

I have 'data' with all columns but 'NEWVAR' and I wish to create it like this:

If score1 %in% SCORE for a particular 'GROUP' then a value '1' is given to 'NEWVAR'

If score2 %in% SCORE & score1 is not in SCORE for a particular 'GROUP' then a value '2' is given to 'NEWVAR'

Comment: @akrun maybe you have a good idea here!!

Comment: I posted a data.table solution.  Please check. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged this [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) using `ifelse` in `data.table` syntax.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, NEWVAR := ifelse(any(SCORE %in% score1), 1, 
                          ifelse(any(SCORE %in% score2), 2, NA_integer_)), GROUP]

data
#    GROUP VAR SCORE NEWVAR
# 1:     1   A     3      1
# 2:     1   B     6      1
# 3:     1   C    NA      1
# 4:     2   A    NA     NA
# 5:     2   B    NA     NA
# 6:     2   C    NA     NA
# 7:     3   A     1      2
# 8:     3   B    NA      2
# 9:     3   C     5      2
#10:     4   A     5      1
#11:     4   B     2      1
#12:     4   C    NA      1
```

I think there is also `fcase` in development version of `data.table` which is similar to `case_when` in `dplyr` and makes writing such nested `ifelse` easy.

Comment: thanks you so much it is great. My question how do I clarify to override if say a GROUP has  SCORE in both score1 and score2--how do I specify to always put a '1' in NEWVAR in those cases? Is it just the order of the if statement?

Comment: Yes, it is order of the conditions that we put in which matters. So if `any(SCORE %in% score1)` is `TRUE` it will always return 1 even if `any(SCORE %in% score2)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: that is great thank you my last thought is why you use 'ifelse' not 'fifelse' ?

Comment: No specific reason. In this case, both of them would work in similar fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
input <- data %>% select(-NEWVAR)
input %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>%
  mutate(NEWVAR=case_when(any(SCORE %in% score1) ~ 1,
                          any(SCORE %in% score2 & !(SCORE %in% score1)) ~ 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scores = list(score1, score2)
ave(data$SCORE, data$GROUP, FUN = function(x){
    chk = sapply(scores, function(y) any(y %in% x))
    seq_along(scores)[chk][1]
})
# [1]  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fifelse` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, NEWVAR := fifelse(any(SCORE %in% score1), 1, 
                          fifelse(any(SCORE %in% score2), 2, NA_integer_)), GROUP]

data
#     GROUP VAR SCORE NEWVAR
# 1:     1   A     3      1
# 2:     1   B     6      1
# 3:     1   C    NA      1
# 4:     2   A    NA     NA
# 5:     2   B    NA     NA
# 6:     2   C    NA     NA
# 7:     3   A     1      2
# 8:     3   B    NA      2
# 9:     3   C     5      2
#10:     4   A     5      1
#11:     4   B     2      1
#12:     4   C    NA      1
```

---

Or with `fcase` from the `devel` version of `data.table`

```
setDT(data)[, NEWVAR := fcase(any(SCORE %in% score1), 1,
                              any(SCORE %in% score2), 2,
                               default = NA_integer_), GROUP]
```